# 8th Wall tap to place example not showing model replacement

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I've replaced the tree.glb model in the ThreeJS placeground example (https://github.com/8thwall/web/tree/master/examples/threejs/placeground), but it's not showing. It works fine when using tree.glb. 
To debug, I've also tried replacing it with the jellyfish-model.glb available in the examples, but it also doesn't show when tapping on the floor plane. 
Is there something wrong with my code, or with the .glb models I'm replacing tree.gbl with?

```
  const modelFile = 'tree.glb' // 3D model to spawn at tap
```

to

```
  const modelFile = 'jellyfish-model.glb' // 3D model to spawn at tap
```

File structure on github: [8thwall-3js-test-github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mszV0.png)

Ideally, I'd like to replicate what I've done using Unity+Vuforia in this example (which basically places a .png onto a floor plane): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poWvXVB4044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by looking at the scale of the 3d model.  The tree model in the link you provided is quite large, so it's being scaled down in size.  See https://github.com/8thwall/web/blob/master/examples/threejs/placeground/index.js#L7-L8

Prove to yourself that the model is being loaded by adding a `console.log('model added!')` type statement into `animateIn()` (as that is the model loaded handler)

My guess is that your jellyfish-model.glb is there, just very small.  Trying adjusting `startScale` and `endScale` to larger values and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the scale from 0.0002 to: `const endScale = new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` ... and the jellyfish pops up now.